# Regex should match binary data

Tags: c#, regex

I have to parse a data file. I want to use regex (.net) and started out with this expression:

```
#mux:(?<mux>[a-z0-9 ]+)#|#curr: (?<curr>\d+)#|#pot:(?<pot>\d+)#|#data#(?<data>\w+)#EOC#
```

My data file contents look like:

```
#pot: 80##curr: 200##mux: rp 0 1 rn 0 2##data# ... binary data ... #EOC#
```

This works fine as Long my data is 888 for instance, but my data consists of binary data, so how can I do this in regex? I 'just' Need a a construct instead of the `\w+` in my data pattern, which matches any character or byte value to be precise.

Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: regex's aren't really for raw binary data, they are for strings.

Comment: you can use . to match any thing.

Comment: It is not a clear question, but perhaps, `(?<data>[^#]+)` is what you need. Else, use `(?<data>(?s:.+?))` to match *any* one or more character but as few as possible.

Comment: What is the **specification** of the binary data format ? Could it contain bytes forming the following sequence `#EOC#` for instance ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using lazy dot pattern `.*?` with a `RegexOptions.Singleline` option:

```
#mux:(?<mux>[a-z0-9 ]+)#|#curr: (?<curr>\d+)#|#pot:(?<pot>\d+)#|#data#(?<data>(?s:.*?))#EOC#
                                                                              ^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%23mux%3A(%3F%3Cmux%3E%5Ba-z0-9%20%5D%2B)%23%7C%23curr%3A%20(%3F%3Ccurr%3E%5Cd%2B)%23%7C%23pot%3A(%3F%3Cpot%3E%5Cd%2B)%23%7C%23data%23(%3F%3Cdata%3E(%3Fs%3A.*%3F))%23EOC%23&i=%23pot%3A%2080%23%23curr%3A%20200%23%23mux%3A%20rp%200%201%20rn%200%202%23%23data%23%20...%20binary%20data%20...%20%23EOC%23)

It will match any 0+ chars as few as possible (up to the first) `#EOC#`.

Comment: THAAAAANKS, give it a try.

Comment: I used an inline modifier group `(?s:...)`, but you can just replace `(?<data>(?s:.*?))` with `(?<data>.*?)` but then you need to pass the `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag to the `Regex.Match`.